# Equivalent statement for Borsuk-Ulam theorem

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

I was going through this [paper](https://jkms.kms.or.kr/journal/view.html?doi=10.4134/JKMS.2012.49.2.251) by Tanaka. In the introduction he says the following
"The classical Borsuk–Ulam theorem can be
restated as the point space is I-trivial."

I am not sure how to go about the proof of this equivalence, what I thought is that any bundle over a point space is just a vector space and it's sphere bundle is just the maximal sphere and we have an obvios $Z_2$ map between the spheres. I don't know where to go from here.

Can anyone suggest something?
thanks and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the terminology of the paper, suppose that the point is not $I$-trivial. Then there exists some vector bundle over a point, say $\alpha$ such that $Ind(\alpha)> dim(\alpha)$, that is there exists $i \geq dim(\alpha)-1$ and a map $S^{i} \rightarrow S(\alpha)$ respecting the antipodal actions on both sides.

So in otherwords, we want to show that:

*There is no $j>i$ and map $F: S^{j} \rightarrow S^{i}$ equivariant with respect to antipodal on both sides* is equivelant to Borsuk-Ulam.

The $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$-equivariance can be restated as saying the $F$ is odd.

Quoting from the wikipedia page on the Borsuk Ulam theorem. "Define a retraction as a function $h:S^{n}\to S^{n-1}$. The Borsuk–Ulam theorem is equivalent to the following claim: there is no continuous odd retraction." A proof of this equivelance is also given there.

Note that the statement we want is in terms of functions $F:S^j \rightarrow S^i$ with $j>i$, but we can always restrict to a standard coordinate subsphere $S^{i+1} \subset S^{j}$ and the restriction will also be an odd function.